# Российских рублей или рубля

Tags: орфография

Как правильно будет и почему (по возможности)

> 1 доллар США = 59.4954783 российских
> рубля

или

> 1 доллар США = 59.4954783 российских рублей

или

> 1 доллар США = 59.4954783 российским рублям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писать, конечно, стоит 59,4954783 российского рубля. Это соответствует правилам, и именно так пишут в приличных изданиях)

Answer (score 1):

***Один доллар США равен пятидесяти девяти целым…*** и далее, если читать по правилам, в конце окажется ***…семистам восьмидесяти трём десятимиллионным российского рубля.***

Но ни один нормальный человек так  произносить не будет. И я в том числе.

А написал бы так (при этом бы нарушил правила!):

***1 доллар США = 59,4954783 российским рублям.***

Comment: Я добавлю ваш вариант в вопрос

Comment: Ну тогда добавьте и "российского рубля".

Comment: Десятичные дроби в русском разве не через запятую записываются?

Comment: Спасибо! Скопировал число из заданного вопроса с точкой, не заметил ошибки.